# Make automatic keypresses register like real keyboard presses C# (and or C++)

Tags: c#, c++, keyboard

I'm trying to get a keypress in C# that would register exactly like a keypress that I would press on my keyboard, some programs don't allow me to write like that as in they ignore the input from command, I've tried `PostMessage()` & `SendKeys.SendWait()`, both of which do **not** register on the program I'm trying to write on. (while my normal key presses do)

I'm looking for a solution in preferably C# but C++ can also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use I putSimulator nuget package:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/520/simulating-keypress-in-the-right-way-using-inputsimulator-with-csharp-in-winforms

It can be used in wpf and windows forms

Comment: it still doesn't register like a real keypress, at least it doesn't write in my program.

Comment: But it writes in other programs?

Comment: yeah, I'm guessing this is because the program is using DirectX?

Comment: Maybe. I just used input simulator and for me it worked